# How to connect tableau to another tool via rest api?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a use case where we have a report built on sigma computing. It’s a business intelligence tool and data here cannot be moved to a database or tableau. We have a report which shows by employee id some data.

We also have another tableau dashboard for employee specific data. What I want is when a user clicks on employee id in this tableau’s dashboard, I want to dynamically generate api call to sigma so that it will open the sigma in a new web page with data prefiltered to that employee id.

Sigma has a rest api, not sure how to achieve this - https://help.sigmacomputing.com/hc/en-us/articles/4408835546003-Get-Started-with-Sigma-s-API

Should I make tableau call a lambda function in aws that will then call the sigma app to render the page? Or is there other ways? A

Haven’t tried it yet

Comment: Tableau cannot natively make API calls from a dashboard. It can do a url action though. Not sure if that's useful for your use case.